# AngularJS Showing mobile version on Chrome

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome

I followed these instructions to start angular:

https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

And for some reason on chrome it shows me the mobile version of the website, but on Safari and Firefox it shows the browser version correctly. How can I make it show the browser version in Chrome?

Comment: go to inspect and press on the "toggle device toolbar" to disable mobile version

Comment: @ArashKiani that's the first thing I tried, the button is off, that's the weird part.